# How long do objects stored in Rails' sessions persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

If I do `session[:greeting] = "Hi!"` in one controller action, for how long will I be able to refer to `session[:greeting]` in other controller actions?

Until the user closes his browser?

Until a certain amount of time passes?

Also, how can I configure this value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Until the user closes her browser. That's the definition of a session.

To configure something longer, you will need to use one of:

- cookies. These can be marked to stay for any period of time (or until the user closes the browser)
- have the user log in

Often there's a combination of these, where the user is given a "remember me" token as a cookie, so that they don't have to log in every time they restart the browser.

Comment: Is there something like session[:greeting] = "Hi!" that would perish when the user went to a different URL or path on the app? (Or just earlier than closing the browser...) This may be bad practice, but I just used the session to store a variable that I needed to persist across AJAX requests on a certain page.

Comment: Look at the "flash" behavior. It's a hash stored in the session that is reset after the next request (with some subtleties).

Comment: I don't understand why logging in would result in the session variable persisting longer. Could you explain?

Comment: I guess I was (vaguely) proposing that if the user logs in, then you can persist the value with whatever user record you keep for her.

Answer (score 3):

It is available until the user closes their browser.